# Как занести ModelAndView в файл?

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf, controller, java

Пишу на Spring java. В контроллере уже имеется метод, который создает и возвращает ModelAndView в правильном формате PDF - файла, красиво отформатированном со всякими украшалками, которые не хочется делать заново. Можно воспользоваться этим методом, чтобы создать именно PDF-файл? Что для этого надо?

Например, можно ли вызвать этот метод контроллера из другого метода, получить созданную модель и записать ее просто побайтово в файл? Выйдет из этого что-то путное?

Или я получу просто в таком случае код HTML?

Comment: Мне не надо как ответ от сервера, надо просто автоматически формировать отчет и посылать по email.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно всё это. Почему это именно метод контроллера? В этом методе есть входящие параметры? Тогда для выхова его из другого метода нужно будет эти параметры передавать, а они приходят с клиента... С точки зрения построения кода, логичнее вынести создание PDF в отдельный метод, а его уже вызывать из контроллера, например, так более гибко будет.

По-хорошему, в контроллере должно быть минимум строк кода. Если вам нужно вернуть PDF в качестве ответа с сервера, то, помимо ModelAndView, контроллеры могут возвращать ещё много чего. Например, ResponseEntity, с generic-параметром byte[], плюс добавить заголовки в response, что вы возвращаете application/pdf. Привели бы свой код, чтобы было более ясно, что и зачем.

Comment: Просто там гигантский код, написанный другим человеком, которого я даже не знаю. Он уже давно ушел из фирмы. И там получается страница в формате PDF нужного вида. Там в ней и графики, и таблицы. И еще он jrxml гигантский использовал. Вот и думала, что можно не тратить время на разбор этого кода. Но, видимо, это неправильный подход. Придется разбираться, как он там все наформатировал.

Comment: Может, есть средства для облегчения форматирования информации pdf? Для рисования там таблиц и графиков?

Comment: Есть всякие библиотеки такие, IText, Apache PDF, но я с ними не работал, ничего не могу сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если метод ModelAndView возвращает pdf, то скорее всего при записи в файл  с расширением .pdf должно получится то, что вы хотите.